# My IP still not changing with proxies in python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

```
`import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Bs4
proxy = {
    'http:': 'http://31.186.239.244:8080',
    'https:': 'http://31.186.239.244:8080'
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'TE': 'Trailers',
    }


old_ip = requests.get("https://2ip.ru")
soup = Bs4(old_ip.text, "lxml")
n1 = soup.find("div", class_="ip")
print(n1.find("span").text)
print()

#
new_ip = requests.get("https://2ip.ru", proxies=proxy, headers=headers)
soup2 = Bs4(new_ip.text, "lxml")
n2 = soup2.find("div", class_="ip")

print(n2.find("span").text) `
```

This code isn't working. In both cases i got the same IP. If proxy is using in Windows (set in Windows settings), it is working. But why it isn't working in code?

Tried another proxies, changed http/https in dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `:` from the dictionary keys:

```py
proxy = {
    'http': 'http://31.186.239.244:8080',
    'https': 'http://31.186.239.244:8080'
}
```